Application launcher does not collapse automatically
I am using kubuntu 22.04 with KDE plasma 5.24.7 and I have a problem with the application launcher in the taskbar.
When I click on the App Launcher and I choose an application to launch, the app launches OK but the menu does not collapse automatically as a result of that. It stays developed over the newly launched application until I click again on the application launcher icon.
I don't remember having this problem with previous releases of this distro.
Any insights on this?
Thanks.

I finally found where the problem is. My taskbar at the top was set to "autohide", apparently, this prevents the menu from wrapping up when an application is launched or on a click outside the menu.
All is good now.
